# localhost return normal value, deploy server return 404 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, tomcat

I was make some controller and test is success, so build and deploy server

In my local, It return normal (like BadRequest) but when after build, in server it return always 404

```
@Api
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/log")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LogController {
    private final LogService logService;
    @ApiOperation("insertLog")
    @PostMapping("")
    public RestResponse selectManager (@AuthenticationPrincipal AdminDTO adminDTO, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody LogDTO param){

        System.out.println("insertLog");

        return RestResponse.builder()
                .restResponseCode(RestResponseCode.SUCCESS)
                .data(logService.insertLog(adminDTO, request.getRemoteAddr(), param)).build();
    }
}
```

In server, I can't find any error in server log and find same code

How I can solve this? or What I'll find other code?

Comment: I was solved.
Because Jenkins not work by authority of ubuntu, then server's class file not changed
WAS(I used Tomcat)'s authority and Jenkins's authority was different